# SQLite get single row position inside result query without using loop

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

With sql query I get 100 result rows. I need to know single row position inside this 100 rows. I have unique fields which I can check by loop, but this takes long time. Is there a way that I can get single item position inside queried result.

For example: I have table with unique user ids`(12, 13, 20, 21, 34, 5)`. These users are ordered by create date. How can I get user position with `id = 34` with sql query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optimizing SQL query is always more efficient that operating on huge results.

Make a `select` with `where` clause in which you will be checking how many users have lesser creation date than desired id owner

```
SELECT 
    count(*) 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    creationDate < (SELECT creationDate FROM table WHERE id = 34)
```

Then the record position is the value of above select (or you will need to add 1 depends on if you are counting from 0 or 1).

---

If creation date can be repeated you will need to handle this situation depends on how you treat the records with same `creationDate` (maybe simple `creationDate <= ...` is enough for you)

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
SELECT row ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columnChoosen) AS row, columnChoosen FROM yourTable) sub WHERE sub.columnChoosen = 34
```